# Open multiple links in same Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

**Im trying to Open multiple links in same Iframe, as well as changing the divsstyle.visibility(Visibility is working for me) but adding window.open I get nothing. I have the original address in a div id="testing" name="wordp" **

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function wordpaboutme() {
                   var showme2 = document.getElementById("testing");
                    showme2.style.visibility = "visible";

                    var changeme = document.getElementById("testing");
                    changeme.window.open.('http://mysite.com/main/about-me/','wordp');  

                }
            </script>
```

---

```
<body>
    <div id="testing" name="wordp" class="bloger" ><iframe src="http://mysite.com/main/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="990" height="800"  >
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p> 
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.open` opens a popup window. It doesn't change what's in an `iframe`.
To open a different page in an `iframe`, consider changing the "`src`" attribute of the iframe with `JQuery`

Also, as Collin Grady has mentioned in the comment, it is an even simpler method to specify the iframe id in the "target" attribute of the link, to do the job.

Comment: Furthermore, it's possible to make a link open in this iframe by simply using `target="wordp"`